# Grouping timestamp field by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write an SQL query to return how many links were submitted to my website over the last 7 day period. So far I have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `count`
FROM `links`
WHERE `created` > NOW() - 86400
AND `created` < NOW()
```

this works for one day, it returns one row called `count` with the number of links submitted in the last 24 hours. I need to change it to return 2 columns called `date` and `count`, with 7 rows (one for each day).

The tricky part that I can't get my head around is that `created` is a `timestamp` column, and I don't have access to change it so I have to work with it.

Edit: work in progress for the query:

```
SELECT DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) AS day, COUNT(id) count
FROM links
GROUP BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))
LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOW()` actually shouldn't be working as it returns a `datetime`. Also, if you want to fetch 7 days worth of data, you want to subtract `604800` from `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. You can use then `date` and `time` functions with `FROM_UNIXTIME`. This will make grouping easier. Optimally, your column should be of `datetime` type.

It would go something like:

```
SELECT DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) day, COUNT(id) count
FROM links
WHERE created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 604800 AND created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))
```

You can alternatively use the `BETWEEN` operator:

```
WHERE created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 604800 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1423/1)